# tensorflow 学習のためのミニバッチを生成するコマンド

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflowの多層NNを作ろうとしていますが、色々調べましたが元データからミニバッチを生成するコマンドが分かりません。例えば
データ　X（１０００行、１０列）　教師データ　Y（１０００行、１列）から１００個のミニバッチをランダムに生成するためのコマンドを教えて頂けませんか？

Answer (score 1):

shuffle_batch()関数にて実現できます。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch

使用方法は以下に記載があります。
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

```
 example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
  min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
```

Comment: 有難うございました。教えて頂いた、スクリプトで作成しexample_batchとlabel_batch をsess.run(train_step, feed_dict={data:example_batch, label:label_batc})に入れて計算いたしましたところ、データの形が合わない（tensorは不可）と言うエラーメッセージが出ました。The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.　スカラーにするにはどう変換したら宜しいでしょうか？　すみません初心者なものでよく分かっていませんが、ご指導願えます。

Comment: @Takashi Sato tf.train.shuffle_batch()とは関係なくモデルを作っているあたりに問題がありそうです。質問欄を「編集」にて現在失敗しているコードを記載いただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: リコメンド有難うございました。次のようなスクリプトで解決いたしました。これでミニバッチの機能が果たせているかどうか分かりませんが、取り敢えず動きます。with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for k in range(1000000):
        s_index = np.random.permutation(n)
        for i in range(0,n,bs):
            x_data = X1[s_index[i:(i+bs) if (i+bs)<n else n]]
            y_label = Y1[s_index[i:(i+bs) if (i+bs)<n else n]]
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={data:x_data, label:y_label})